# Django Form ForeignKey save

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Sry for stupid question, but I don't understand. I'm trying to use  Django Forms, I have 2 models

```
class Post(models.Model):
unit = models.ForeignKey('Unit',on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=False)
```

and

```
class Unit(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique = True)
```

I've created a form

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post, Unit, StatusOfPost


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = [
        'unit',
    ]
```

than I've written a view.py

```
def ideaNewForm(request):
unit = Unit.objects.get(name=request.POST['unit'])
user = request.user
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        idea = form.save(commit=False)
        idea.unit = unit
        idea = Post.objects.create(
            author = user,
        )
        return redirect('postsList')
else:
    form = PostForm()
return render(request, 'post_new.html', {'form':form})
```

Unit matching query does not exist.- and i have that such issue.
I have a dropdown list it is a Unit model. How save it right?

Before I did it without Django Form

```
unit   = Unit.objects.get(name=request.POST['unit'])
```

and it worked well, but I want use Django Forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you are trying to get the unit separately. It's what is selected in the form, there is no need to get it; just saving the form will create the post with the selected unit. The only thing you need to do is to add the user.

```
def ideaNewForm(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            idea = form.save(commit=False)
            idea.author = request.user
            idea.save()
            return redirect('postsList')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'post_new.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Thank you, really. I tried to create a bicycle, but everything was easier)))))

Answer (score 1):

You just missing a `['unit']` after `request.POST`:

```
def ideaNewForm(request):
    unit = Unit.objects.get(name=request.POST['unit'])
    (...remaining codes...)
```